# Canvas displays initially in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, chart.js

I am currently developing a simple graphing service. It uses [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) for rendering (Canvas based).

The problem is that the charts don't show up in Firefox 21 initially although they show up in Chrome. If you mouse over a chart, it shows up.

- [Source](https://github.com/bebraw/cdnperf/tree/ff-issue). You can find the relevant bit at [main.js](https://github.com/bebraw/cdnperf/blob/ff-issue/public/js/main.js#L231)

Any insight on the topic is welcome.

**EDIT:** Note that this issue seems to happen randomly if you toggle the links at the top (the CDN names). Not quite sure what's going on there.

**EDIT:** Looks like if I draw something simple (like a line) to the Canvas instead of a chart, the issue disappears in Firefox. Looks like this is a Chart.js specific issue.

**EDIT:** I worked around the issue by enabling animation on Chart.js. I'll leave this question open just in case someone figures out a proper solution. Looks like a bug in Chart.js to me. I [opened an issue](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/122) for keeping track of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a similar issue with Chartjs and Firefox 24, my "fix" was to set animation to true and the animationSteps:1.